# Why does pegjs fail to process the whitespace rule " "*

Tags: javascript, parsing, peg, pegjs

The following simple pegjs grammar works fine:

```
start
  = sentence

sentence
  = word ws sentence
  / word

word
  = [a-z]*

ws
  = " "
```

It is available at http://jsfiddle.net/4V3Zt/  . The gramar can be also pasted into http://pegjs.majda.cz/online .

If I change the ws rule to allow whitespaces arbitrary spaces:

```
ws
  = " "*    // add an asterisk to allow " ", "  ", "   ", ...
```

parsing fails with a maximum callstack exception thrown. (If using jsfiddle, you see the exception in browser tools.The exception comes up in a node.js environment as well, so it is certainly related to pegjs).

**What is wrong with the * in this ws rule?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `*` (for `word` as well).

`*`  can match the empty string; `+` requires at least one instance.